# java -jar to springboot jar returning PID instead of exit code

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, shell, sh

I am trying to execute an sh which has a java -jar and make it return the exit code, but instead it is retrieving me the PID assigned to that process

```
PROCESO="java -Xmx2048m -jar xyz.jar"
echo $?
```

returns the PID

How can i make it return exit code instead ?

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCESO="java -Xmx2048m -jar xyz.jar"
```

is an assignment of the string `"java -Xmx2048m -jar xyz.jar"` to `PROCESO`.

If you want to run java, do it like this:

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar xyz.jar
echo $?
```

This executes `xyz.jar` and echos the exit code.